# execute function only after async fucntion execute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to F1() to wait until F2() fully execute and get rest call response and set some data.

## i tried with this code

```
this.F1().subscribe(result => {
  this.F2(result);
})


    F1() {


      return this.graphDataService.getAvailableSpan(a, b).subscribe(res => {
        this.c = new Date(res.lastAvailableDate);
        return 1;
      }, error => {
        this.lastAvailableDate = new Date();
        return 1;
      })
    }
```

Comment: Have u tried promises or acync await

Comment: i tried but getting error, i am sure i write code wrong

Comment: You can't subscribe to a Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

check this
[How can I call multiple API's on a function with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237272/how-can-i-call-multiple-apis-on-a-function-with-angular)

```
async apicall(){

      let data1 = await f1(); //your first function should return promises
      let data2 = await f2(); //your second function should return promises

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
async getAsyncCall() {
        this.result = await this.httpclient.get(this.URL).toPromise();
        this.F2(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use RxJS operators to make the flow asynchronous. Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.F1().subscribe(result => {
    this.F2(result);
  });
}

F1(): Observable<any> {
  return this.graphDataService.getAvailableSpan(a, b).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      this.c = new Date(res.lastAvailableDate);
    }),
    catchError((error) => {          // <-- `catchError` should return an obervable
      this.lastAvailableDate = new Date();
      return of(error);
    })
  );
}
```